# R studio date fill in dataframe

Tags: r, date, na

I have a dataframe with values and a date, I also have projection values from historical averages.

My question is, how to fill in a date column with sequential dates to fit the  current dataframe row number if the remainder of the dates are NA (my dates range from 2017-07-14 to 2017-09-11, and my dataframe is several rows longer).

See simplified example below:

```
Day <- as.Date(c("2017-01-01","2017-01-02","2017-01-03", NA, NA ))

Value <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
df <- as.data.frame(Day)
df$Value <- Value
```

Requirement is to extrapolate dates for value 4 and 5 using the last date available.

Cheers,

Comment: Your question is unclear, and without a simple example with sample data, you are unlikely to get an answer that really meets your needs. Please take a moment to come up with a very simple example (perhaps a data.frame with a couple of representative columns and a small number of rows that satisfy your base requirements), give us this data using something like `dput` or such, and give us demonstrated output. Otherwise I fear this will simply be down-voted and closed.

Comment: Amended, I am unsure of linking the dataframe output however.

Comment: That is a great example, thank you. Giving us demonstrated output is quite simple: what do you expect the replaced values to be? For instance, I think you are hoping for the linearly-extrapolated dates `"2017-01-04"` and `"-05"`.

Comment: Though a little crude, `Hmisc::approxExtrap` does linear extrapolation; its crudeness is that it strips `POSIXt` and `Date` classes, so you need to re-assign (along with the relevant `origin` ... see the docs). `approx` could work fine given it does not start/end on an `NA` (same `class` caveat).

Answer (score 1):

```
df <- data.frame(date = as.Date(c("2017-01-01", "2017-01-02" "2017-01-03", NA, NA)), 
                 value = 1:5)

df$date <- seq.Date(from = df$date[1], length.out = dim(df)[1], by = "day")
```

See `?seq.Date` for details, I hope this helps.